# How can I add days in a date excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: mysql

How can I add days (3 days) excluding weekends and holidays?

Example: October 16,2015(Friday) + 3 days = October 21,2015(Wednesday)

Here is my query but how can I exclude weekend and holiday? Is that possible?

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY(ISBN,title,author,First_Name,Last_Name,STATUS,DATE,Return_Date,UserID) 
VALUES (i,t,a,f,l,1,NOW(),NOW()+ INTERVAL 3 DAY,u);
```

Comment: You need a calendar table that identifies days as being holidays, weekends, and weekdays.

Comment: @GordonLinoff a table with the list of dates that are weekends and holidays?

Comment: I would go with a `calendar` table that has one row per date, along with information about that date, such as the holiday name and whether it is a weekend or weekday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what should is your exact goal?

My guess if `NOW()` weekday is:

```
Monday (+3) = Thursday
Tuesday (+3) = Friday
Wednesday (+5) = next Monday
Thursday (+5) = next Tuesday
Friday (+5) = next Wednesday
Saturday (+4) = next Wednesday ?
Sunday (+3) = next Wednesday ?
```

If [it is correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc82/3)  then your query could be transformed into:

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY(ISBN,title,author,First_Name,Last_Name,STATUS,DATE,Return_Date,UserID) 
VALUES (i,t,a,f,l,1,NOW(),NOW()+ INTERVAL (IF(WEEKDAY(date1) IN (6,0,1),3,IF(WEEKDAY(date1) = 5,4,5))) DAY,u);
```

If you need to check other holidays and extend the period according to official holiday calendar I would completely agree with @GordonLinoff comment: you need extra table to keep all holidays first. But even with that change made it is not trivial query to get correct date dynamically.